# Gstreamer crackling sound on Raspberry Pi 3 while playing video

Tags: raspberry-pi, gstreamer, alsa

I am playing a hardware accelerated video on the Raspberry Pi 3 using this simple pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=file:///test/test.mp4
```

As soon as the video begins to play, any sound being played in parallel using ALSA begins to crackle (tested with gstreamer and mplayer). It's a simple WAV-file and I am using a USB audio interface.

Listening to the headphone jack already crackles without playing an audio file (but this jack is very low quality and I don't know if that's a different effect).

Playing the audio in the same pipeline as the video does not help. CPU is only on approx. 30 % load and there's plenty of free memory. I already overclocked the SD card. Playing two videos in parallel with omxplayer has no impact and sound still plays well. But as soon as I start the pipe above, the sound begins to crackle.

I tried "stress" to simulate high CPU load. This had no impact either, so CPU does not seem to be the problem (but maybe the GPU?).

This is the gstreamer pipeline to test the audio:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=/test/test.wav ! wavparse ! audioconvert ! alsasink device=hw:1,0
```

GST_DEBUG=4 shows no problems.

I tried putting queues on different places but nothing helped. Playing a video without audio tracks works a little bit better. But I have no idea, where the ressource shortage may lie, if it even is one.

It somehow seems like gstreamer is disturbing audio streams.

Any ideas where the problem may be are highly appreciated.

Comment: What if you play via `autoaudiosink`? We don't know anything about your setup. Maybe the primary audio output is done via pulseaudio and accessing the hardware directly via alsa causes the interference.

Comment: Pulse also uses alsa as backend. I tried also with pulse and it did not change. I am suspecting USB problems on the Raspberry, as suspected also in this thread: https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/2215. My audio interface also has a binterval of 1.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the USB driver of my interface is expecting a very responsive system. I bought a cheap new USB audio interface with a bInterval value of 10 instead of 1 and everything works fine now. More details can be found here: https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/2215